# How do I use .fill method to create new objects?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

Specifically, I'm wondering why when I create a new array with several sub-arrays using .fill, the sub-arrays created using .fill are the same object.

```
array = Array.new.fill([], 0..8)

subsquare[0].object_id => 7220340
subsquare[1].object_id => 7220340
```

How would I create these sub-arrays while ensuring each sub-array was its own object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The why to this question can be found if you look at Array.new:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html

> Note that the second argument populates the array with references to
>   the same object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you
>   need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as
>   Symbols, numbers, true or false.
>
> To create an array with separate objects a block can be passed
>   instead. This method is safe to use with mutable objects such as
>   hashes, strings or other arrays

The workaround as specified in the doc is:

```
array = Array.new(8) { [] }
```